# How to use source map files on different OS

Tags: javascript, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

I use source map for js files both on production and dev server, so I just load it from the local store. In this case, I use next string at the end of files //# sourceMappingURL=file:////var/www/static/. which points at my local store. But I want to use it on both operation system Linux and Windows. So for Windows, this string is not valid file:////var/www/static/, I should use file:////C:/www/static/. In this case on Linux browser can get this file. Is any possibility to use some universal reference which will work in both OS

Comment: The sourcemap tells the **client** how to load the file.  The client should have no concept of your servers actual filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sourcemap tells the client how to load the file.  The client should have no concept of your servers actual filesystem.

The mapping should really be: `# sourceMappingURL=/path/to/file.js.map` where `/path/to/file.js.map` would resolve to: `http://www.example.com/path/to/file.js.map`

The client is completely agnostic to filesystems.

Additionally, you should not be service resources over the `file://` protocol.

Comment: what is the problem with file:// protocol. Why I should use http://www.example.com/path/to/file.js.map, if I want hide map files on production how I can do this in this case.  I just want to create one gulpfile.js which will nice work with different os and will be good for dev and production.